# How do I get border into corner of webpage?

Tags: html, css

Please see image for problems with CSS. I want the blue corners to fill the corners but there seems to always be a gap. I appreciate this may be a simple question but would be grateful for help.

[photo of webpage and problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tuu7A.png)

Comment: Remove padding and margin on the body

html, body {
padding:0px;
margin: 0px;
}

Comment: @vicgoyso Answers should generally not be posted as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding and margin on the body

```
html, body { 
  padding:0px; 
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you have literally made my day :)